# Problem with 'default' constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following table

```
create table interiors
(id integer, name varchar(20), type varchar(20) default 'baby cot', price integer)
```

When I don't insert any value of 'type', by the definition of table, it should take the default value.  But when I fetch all rows by 'select' query, it doesn't show default value.

Can anyone tell me that what is the problem?

Thanks & regards,
Pooja.

Comment: Actually I think I might have misread the question  Can you confirm whether the issue is that you were expecting the default to apply to pre-existing rows or that it doesn't apply to newly inserted rows? If the latter can you show us the `insert` statement you are using? Are you explicitly inserting `NULL` for example?

Comment: see, when I m not inserting any value into 'type' column, then by the 'default' constraint, it should show default value. when i fetch all rows, 'type' shows no value. for the next, when i insert NULL(without quotation) in 'type' column then select query shows that 'NULL' word. i want the output that, when i m not inserting anything into 'type' column, it should show default type as 'baby cot'.

Comment: Why are you inserting `NULL` if you want it to have the default? You need to either do `insert into interiors(id,name,price) values (1,'foo',100)` OR `insert into interiors(id,name,type,price) values (1,'foo',DEFAULT,100)` inserting `NULL` isn't treated any differently then inserting any other explicit value.

Answer (score 1):

Defaults apply to data that is inserted when the default is active not to `select` statements against the table.

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to say exactly. Will you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is for you but here is some hints for you what is going on.

This T-SQL

```
declare @T table (ID int, Name varchar(10) default 'DEF')

insert into @T (ID, Name) values (1, 'VAL')
insert into @T (ID, Name) values (2, null)
insert into @T (ID) values (3)
insert into @T (ID, Name) values (4, default)

select ID, Name
from @T
```

Have this result

```
ID          Name
----------- ----------
1           VAL
2           NULL
3           DEF
4           DEF
```

Default constraint is not used when you specify a value for a column as in row 1 and 2 but it is used when you omit the column from the insert or you specify `default`. It is also not used when you do a select.

If you want a default value instead of null on select you can use `coalesce`.

```
select ID, coalesce(Name, 'DEF') as Name
from @T
```

Result

```
ID          Name
----------- ----------
1           VAL
2           DEF
3           DEF
4           DEF
```

Comment: +1. You could also show `insert into @T (ID, Name) values (4,default)`